# How do I use Lucene to index and search structure text files?

Tags: java, lucene, indexing

This is the first time I use Lucene, and I have a text file like this :

```
id,name,address,hobby
1,namm1,address1,football
2,namm2,address2,football
3,namm3,address3,football
4,namm4,address4,football
5,namm5,address5,football
6,namm6,address6,basketball
7,namm7,address7,basketball
8,namm8,address1,football
9,namm9,address8,swimming
...
```

The file above is a text file which contains 1,000,000 lines. Now I want to find the record whose address is `address1` and its hobby is `football` from the file, and then put the record into another file like this:

```
1,namm1,address1,football
8,namm8,address1,football
...
```

The first file is extremely large, so it would be very slow to find the record one after another. I want to and build an index (according to address and hobby) for the first file with Lucene. Then I can quickly find the record whose address is `address1` and its hobby is `football`, and put it in a new file. I have never programmed with Lucene. Who can give me a similar example?

Comment: Why are you so eager to use lucene for it? lucene, and IR in general is usually used for non-structured text. For structured text, you can use a structured data base, and sql - which will probably be much simpler

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Actually, the problem I met was much more complicated. In order to make the problem clearly, I simplified it. I have used database to solve the problem. But later, tens of millions of  records need to be updated, and large number of temporary tables need to be built. Both time complexity and space complexity are too difficult.So I want to try with Lucene. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple. When you index a file with Lucene, you can define your own "Analyzer". In a nutshell, the analyzer extracts information from a source and puts it into "fields" of a lucene "document".

When you search something, you can define which fields Lucene should consider.

So the solution in your case is to write an analyzer which puts each column into a field. Use a `MultiFieldQueryParser` and in your query, specify the field names. For your example, the query would be

```
address:address1 hobby:football
```

Comment: I'll just put my comment in an answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think he needs to write an analyzer at all, he can just use java code to parse each line an put each value in the appropriate field, using one of the many built in analyzers